# Why am I getting a dictionary error in from my partial view in my MVC Application?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have an edit view on my MVC web app that has some partial views in it.  The purpose of the partial views is to allow a user to add data to a dropdown list that is perhaps missing.  The partial views work on the `create` view but not the `edit` view.  When you try to edit a car the parial view throws an error of:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'MyProject.Models.Car', but this dictionary requires a model item
>   of type 'MyProject.Models.Manufacturer'.

Here is a snapshot of my code.  I'm using Ajax forms for everything I do here.

**Edit**

```
@model MyProject.Models.Car

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Car", new AjaxOptions { 
    HttpMethod = "POST", 
    OnSuccess = "success" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    ...form fields etc
}
@Html.Partial("_Manufacturer")
```

**_Manufacturer (partial view)**

```
@model MyProject.Models.Manufacturer
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Manufacturer", new AjaxOptions { 
    HttpMethod = "POST", 
    OnSuccess = "success" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    ...form fields etc
}
```

As you can see, the edit view allows you to edit a car whilst the partial view, which is triggered as a modal (bootstrap 4.0), allows you to add manufacturers to one of the dropdown lists should they be missing.

I'm not sure as to why this causes a dictionary error though, the `Manufacturer` model is defined in the partial view and so shouldn't be using the `Car` model.  Is this related to the fact we are editing a specific record and therefore pass an ID as a parameter?

Comment: `@Html.Partial("_Manufacturer")` does not pass a model as a parameter, the context of the view that calls this partial has a model of `MyProject.Models.Car` so that is what will be passed to the Partial.  If you want the partial to have a different model, pass whatever model you want in the Partial call

Comment: The partial view is expecting an instance of a `Manufacturer` object, but you're not providing it one: `@Html.Partial("_Manufacturer")`  Is there a property on your `Car` object which is of type `Manufacturer` that you should be supplying?

Answer (score 3):

When you call your partial:

```
@Html.Partial("_Manufacturer")
```

You are not passing it a model.  This means it will implicitly pass whatever the model of the calling view is, in your case that is a `MyProject.Models.Car`.

What you need to do is add the model to the `@Html.Partial()` call:

```
//Assuming your Car class has a Manufacturer property
@Html.Partial("_Manufacturer", Model.Manufacturer)
```

Comment: This may be where my confusion is.  The partial view is supposed to use the `Models.Manufacturer` model for its data because it's just a form to update a different table.  The `manufacturer` is not in the `Cars` table.

Comment: @Yanayaya This is where you should create a view model that will have a Cars instance _and_ a Manufacturer instance.  It is not often that an MVC app is _strictly_ MVC.  Most of the time a ViewModel is required so that multiple classes/models can be handled in one View/UI